# Angular slow hide/show

Tags: angularjs

I have some code to hide and show slides as follows:

```
<img ng-src="{{slide}}" ng-repeat="slide in slides" ng-show="$index == onSlide">

<a id="previousButton" type="button" ng-show="onSlide" class="left carousel-control" ng-click="onSlide = onSlide - 1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>
<a id="nextButton" type="button" ng-hide="onSlide == slides.length - 1" class="right carousel-control" ng-click="onSlide = onSlide + 1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
```

Performance is great when using the buttons, the slides switch immediately. However, if I change `scope.onSlide` in the controller, there is an extreme delay in the slide switching, although a console.log reveals `scope.onSlide` is indeed incrementing immediately. What could be causing the lag?

Relevant controller code:

```
scope.$on("videoTimeChanged", function(event, time) {

    if (scope.videoState == "playing") {
        if (time > scope.scenario.presentation[0].syncManifest[scope.onSlide]) scope.onSlide++;
    }

});
```

As you can see, I'm listening for a time event, which will fire every 250 ms or so, and comparing the time to the time at which the slide is supposed to change. If the current time is greater, I increment the slide. when i watch the various parts of this in console.log, it all works perfectly behind the scenes.

Comment: Is this on a desktop or mobile browser? You seeing this in all different browsers?

Comment: Only checked in chrome so far. I'll check the others

Comment: If I am changing onSlide while firing repeated broadcast events in quick succession (to track the current time, for instance), would this cause the ui thread to block and perhaps cause this behavior?

Comment: I think you need to show us your controller code as well

Comment: Added relevant controller code

Comment: Ok just discovered adding scope.$digest() after the scope.onSlide++ fixes the issue. Why would this be necessary though when using the buttons works fine? I guess there is less for the digest loop to process when its only the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

That probably happens because ng-repeat creates a new scope, and in ng-show you assign a primitive value instead of an object.

Try creating an object in your controller like $scope.carousel.onSlide and assign ng-show to carousel.onSlide instead.

Please do refer to carousel.onSlide inside all ng-clicks as well.

a classic: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot

Comment: This didnt seem to do it, but that is an interesting video

Comment: The buttons should hide show based on `onSlide` as well. They perform exactly the same way and they are in the main scope. Its about a 2 second delay before any update when I increment `onSlide` in the Ctrl.

Comment: Don't know if this is relevant, but the increment is occurring inside a `scope.$on()`.

Comment: I edited my answer, ng-click should refer to the same object.